# Angular2 Switch page without having to click router-link

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to switch pages without having to click a [router-link]="" html element?

**EDIT: Updated code which is Working**

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'menu'
})
@View({
  templateUrl: '/views/menu.html',
  directives: []
})
export class Menu {

  constructor(public router: Router) {
  }

  navigate() { // Called by (click)= on element in .html
    this.router.navigate(['/Net_int_config']);
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you can use [navigate and navigateByUrl](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Router-class.html)

Comment: @EricMartinez I'm attempting to use  this.router.parent.navigate(['/Home']);  in a child component but I keep getting "Cannot read property 'navigate' of null" Any idea?

Comment: Why are you using `parent`? It should be `this.router.navigate...`

Comment: Okay. When should parent be used then? I thought I had to use it as my routes were set inside of the parent/app.ts file?

Comment: The paths of the files are not related to the paths of the routes.