# Angular 2 - I'm trying to navigate to another route using router.parent.navigate

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular 2 - I'm trying to navigate to another route using router.parent.navigate.

However, the error I get is this: "EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of null" in my console log.

**This is my current code:**

```
 import {Component, View, bootstrap, bind, provide} from 'angular2/angular2';
 import {Router, ROUTER_BINDINGS, RouterOutlet, RouteConfig, RouterLink, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, APP_BASE_HREF} from 'angular2/router';
 import {Location, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';

 import {Todo} from './components/todo/todo';
 import {About} from './components/about/about';
 import {AuthService} from './authService';

 @Component({
     selector: 'app'
 })

 @View({
     template: `
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a [router-link]="['/Home']">Todo</a></li>
                <li><a [router-link]="['/About']">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
     `,
     directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink]
 })

 @RouteConfig([
     { path: '/', redirectTo: '/home' },
     { path: '/home', component: Todo, as: 'Home' },
     { path: '/about', component: About, as: 'About' }
 ])

 export class AppComponent {
     constructor(_router: Router, _authService: AuthService, _location: Location){

         _router.subscribe((val) => {       

             _authService.isUserLoggedIn().then((success) => {               

                 //This part below is not working:
                     _router.parent.navigate(['/About']);

            });      

        })
    }
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/'}), AuthService]);
```

Comment: Like I've [already told you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569347/angular2-switch-page-without-having-to-click-router-link?noredirect=1#comment55075332_33569347), it should be `_router.navigate(['/About']);`. `Router` [does not have a `parent` property`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/router/router.ts).

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hmmm... yes it does: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Router-class.html  _router.parent.navigate(['About']); just remove the forward slash so it is relative to the parent and not the root

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the ngOnInit method.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 

constructor(router: Router, authService: AuthService, location: Location){

}

ngOnInit(){
     this.router.subscribe((val) => {       

         this.authService.isUserLoggedIn().then((success) => {               

             //This part below is not working:
                 this.router.parent.navigate(['/About']);

        });      

    })
}
}
```