# The page does not show complete in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I am using Angular 2 beta (TypeScript).

When I click the link using `<a [routerLink]="['Friends']">Friends</a>` to go to this page, it shows both the text **friends list:** and **IDs** well.

However, when I use the code `this._router.navigate(['/Friends']);` to go to this page, it can only show the text **friends list:**, but no **IDs**.

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'friends-component'
})
@View({
    template: `
        friends list:
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="#friend of friends">
                {{friend.id}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    `
})
export class FriendsComponent {
    public friends = FRIENDS;
}

var FRIENDS: any[] = [
    { "id": 11 },
    { "id": 22 },
    { "id": 33 },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because my code `this._router.navigate(['/Friends']);` runs outside of the Angular zone. Check [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/NgZone-class.html) for details.

The solution is:

First

```
import {NgZone} from 'angular2/core';
```

Second, add this

```
constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone) {}
```

Third, change the code to

```
this._ngZone.run(() => {
    this._router.navigate(['/Friends']);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use

```
this._router.parent.navigate(['/Friends']):
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not help, still same result.  For yours, I don’t know the difference between `this._router.parent.navigate` and `this._router.navigate`. But they both work. Check [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668857/angular-2-im-trying-to-navigate-to-another-route-using-router-parent-navigate) under the question.

Comment: It would be best to add a bit of explanation why this is the right solution.

Comment: I think this was the right solution in a older alpha of Angular 2. Sorry. But the API changes fast.

Comment: @HongboMiao Thanks. Hope you find the solution.